# How to set Layout weight for Widgets in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am very new for android and in my app I want to set Textviews like my below image and for this I wrote the code below, then all Textviews widths become equal.

But I want to set Textviews like my below image.

Please help me.

### code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Color"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
          />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Give `android:layout_weight="1"` to second `TextView` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to pass `weightSum` to `Root layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Color"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
          />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Krish Welcome. Check mark as correct answer thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

> A 2:1:7 ratio might work better

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Color"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
          />
```